# fast and simple constraint programming involving vectors (arrays)

Tags: c++, c++11, constraints, constraint-programming

I have many,many, many vectors that I need to check for duplicates of numbers with some very basic first order logic.

I can use intersections, but that is proving to be too slow. I thought I could turn this into a bitwise problem. The full set of integers are known and each vector/array could be represented as a bitset, but I can only find a half a solution.

I currently use looping and vector intersection but it is proving to be too slow for the amount of problems I need to check.

For a simple example, given:

```
E: 1 2
F: 2 4
M: 1 3
N: 4 5  
A: 5 6
```

The problem I am trying to identify, is always a larger format of:

```
(E || F) && (M || N) && A -> which is proven as possible by selecting F,M,A.
```

I need to verify if the above is possible without duplicates.

Is there a means of examining vectors/arrays like this that is faster than 9 million loops?
Are the constraint libraries the only option?

**In an effort to clarify:**

containers are std::vector.

The vectors contain any integer.

I would need to examine them problem by problem to identify the full set of integers.

Using the conditional logic specified to select entire vectors, will a duplicate occur?
The conditional operators in use would always be "AND" and "OR" only. The problem I listed is a simplified version, but that is really all there is to it. It just differs in size.

The output I care less about..it could be a boolean, another vector of potential duplicates, etc. I am trying to find the right tool for the job rather than salvaging.

In my current set up, I would solve this by analyzing for forced items like A and removing anything it intersects with...(in this case, N...then I would loop again, and do the same process with M, which is now a forced choice, and removing E, leaving me with F.

Comment: Your problem is badly specified.  If `E` is a vector than `(E || F)` is an invalid expression.  Please edit your question and restate the algorithmic requirements more precisely and thoroughly.  What is exactly the full inventory of the _input_ to the algorithm.  What is the algorithm expected to _output_.  What is the exact relationship between the input and output?

Comment: I think what he means is to get some set of vectors of numbers and an expression of their relation (in form he didn't specify so I assume it's hardcoded), and he wants to choose set that have no duplicate numbers - in his example expression says to chose `(either E or F) and (either M or N) and A` in such a way that chosen vectors contain no duplicates.

Comment: Yes J_Kubik, that is exactly what I meant :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem correctly this is a set partition problem, where the values from a certain "universe" (i.e. all values in the sets) should be selected so that one value is just in one of the selected sets. And to this is a certain condition which possible combinations of the sets are possible.

I have implemented the stated (simple) problem in MiniZinc (a very high level Constraint Programming system, see my MiniZinc page for more info and further links: http://www.hakank.org/minizinc/ ).

The model is here: http://www.hakank.org/minizinc/set_partition_stackoverflow.mzn
and is copied below in full:

```
include "globals.mzn";

int: n = 5; % number of sets

array[1..n] of set of int: s = 
  [
   {1,2}, % E
   {2,4}, % F
   {1,3}, % M
   {4,5}, % N 
   {5,6}  % A
  ];

% All values (the "universe")
set of int: values = {j | i in 1..n, j in s[i]};

% decision variables
array[1..n] of var bool: x; % which set (in s) to select
array[1..n] of var set of values: xs; % the selected sets

solve satisfy;
% Minimize the number of selected sets
% solve minimize sum(i in 1..n) (bool2int(card(xs[i]) > 0));

constraint 

  % The condition
  % (E || F) && (M || N) && A
  ((x[1] \/ x[2]) /\ (x[3] \/ x[4]) /\ x[5])
  /\ 
  forall(i in 1..n) (
     % If this set is selected (in x[i]), put s[i] in xs[i]
     (x[i]  xs[i] = s[i])
     /\ % ensure not selected sets are represented as {} in xs
     (not(x[i])  card(xs[i]) = 0)
  )
  /\ % make sure that a value is selected in exactly one set
  partition_set([xs[i] | i in 1..n], values)
;

output
[
  "x: " ++ show(x) ++ "\n" ++ 
  "xs: " ++ show(xs) ++ "\n"
];
```

There is a single solution for this problem:

```
x: [false, true, true, false, true]
xs: [{}, {2, 4}, {1, 3}, {}, 5..6]
```

where "x" is a boolean array if a set should be selected or not, and "xs" contains the selected sets (if a set is not selected then the element is {}, i.e. empty). The partition of the sets is done with the `partition_set` function which ensures that a value is in one set and that all values in the universe (the set "values") are in some set.

I'm not sure if this MiniZinc model helps at all but you may see it as a kind of inspiration if nothing else. Also, the handling of the condition is hard coded in this model so it's not addressed here.

The C++ based CP system Gecode (http://www.gecode.org/) has support for set variables and a partition constraint (called "disjoint" in Gecode), though I have not tested it for this problem.
Here is an example of how "disjoint" can be used in a standard partition problem: http://www.hakank.org/gecode/set_partition.cpp .